# Use ULong as function parameter in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

Can I use `ULong` as a parameter in function definition in Kotlin?

My code looks like below:

```
import androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color

fun EColor(value: ULong) = Color(value)
val Red700 = EColor(0xffdd0d3c)
```

Then I got an error looks like:
[image: compiler error]

`Conversion of signed constants to unsigned ones is prohibited`

If I call `val Red700 = Color(0xffdd0d3c)`, then it works fine.

So how come I got this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are [unsigned literals](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/basic-types.html#literals) in Kotlin. You write them by adding a `u` or `U` suffix:

```
val Red700 = EColor(0xffdd0d3cU)
```

You can also call `toULong`:

```
val Red700 = EColor(0xffdd0d3c.toULong())
```